# Flex yylineno set to 1

Tags: flex-lexer

I'm writing a simple parser for tcpdump logs, could you please tell me why I can't get proper line number?

```
%{
char str[80];
%}
%option yylineno

...
%%

^{HOURS}:{MINUTES}:{MINUTES} if(input()=='.') { strcpy(str, yytext);  BEGIN(A); } else {printf("Wrong hour %d", yylineno); }
<A>({NDPS}|{DPS})\.({NDPS}|{DPS})\.({NDPS}|{DPS})|\.{NDPS} printf("Wrong IP!, %d", yylineno);
<A>[ ]{DPS}\.{DPS}\.{DPS}\.{DPS} strcat(str, " from "); strcat(str, yytext+1); BEGIN(B);
...
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When I tried this, it turned out that I had to have a rule that actually matches newline for yylineno to be updated. With the following rule it worked, and without it yylineno never changed:

```
\n { }
```

Comment: Thanks for saving a lot of time. It's very hard to find useful tips for the usage of flex.

Comment: Note that if you are not using `flex` (but are using `lex` or some other variant of it), this may not be sufficient.  See [Lex: `yylineno` returning 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524630/lex-yylineno-returning-1) for some information (or, short form, replace `\n { }` with `\n { yylineno++; }`).  If you are using `flex`, this is probably not a good idea — it probably double-increments the line number, which is probably counter-productive.

Comment: If we're anyway adding the rule to increment line number, why not create our own lineno variable independent of flex's internals? put `int my_yylineno=1` in declaration region, and `\n {my_yylineno++;}` in rules

Comment: EXCELLENT! IT WORKS